# Hide System Function or disallow the use of it

Tags: c#

E.g.: I wrote a wrapper for the `DataTime.Now` function called `ServerTime.Now` where I set a div to the Time of the SQL Server the App is connected to during Startup.

Now I would like to "hide" the `DateTime.Now` function somehow to make sure no developer is using it any more in his code. Is there a way to do this in C# (and if not is it possible with Resharper or any other tool)?

Comment: Do you mean in just your app or in any app used on that computer?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200628/prevent-other-developers-using-base-methods-within-a-class) (using StyleCop or FxCop with a rule).

Comment: The answer in the other question is solving my problem. Thanks!!!

Answer (score -2):

> > Is there a way to do this in C#

no

> > with Resharper or any other tool

no

Comment: Yes, there is... Not "hide" per se, but one can use code inspection to flag usage of certain constructs.